# How to run the authorization rake task for paperclip-dropbox?

Tags: paperclip, dropbox

I want to use [paperclip-dropbox](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox) but I don't succeed making it work :

```
$ rake dropbox:authorize APP_KEY=your_app_key APP_SECRET=your_app_secret ACCESS_TYPE=dropbox|foobar

foobar : commande introuvable

[7]+ Stoppé
```

Do you know how to make it pass ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ACCESS_TYPE` should either be `dropbox` or `app_folder`, depending on how you set up the permissions for your app.

I'm guessing you're using app folder permissions, so please try this:

`rake dropbox:authorize APP_KEY=abc123 APP_SECRET=xyz789 ACCESS_TYPE=app_folder`

but replace abc123 and xyz789 with your app key and secret.

Comment: Oops, rake is not happy : `And after you approved the authorization confirm it here (y/n): y
rake aborted!
root must be :dropbox, :app_folder, or :auto`

Comment: I passed the name of my app on dropbox.

Comment: You should pass the exact string "app_folder".

Comment: Ah ah ah, I'm such a moron ! Thank you for your help, it was very useful !

Comment: I got the same problem and imho the gem messages are not clear. Gem is asking to pass symbols :auto, atc..but only strings works.